# Can I specify a custom default value to be used when migrating after adding a new parent class in a Django model?

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, makemigrations

I am writing a Django app that provides a very simple model called `Submittable`, which users of the app are supposed to inherit from when they want to use other functionalities of the app.

```py
# app1
class Submittable(models.Model):
    is_submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # other methods here

# app2
class Paper(Submittable):
    # some fields
```

However, when I add this as a parent to an already existing model in another app and run `makemigrations`, I am asked to provide a default value to the new field `submittable_ptr_id`. The problem is, that I want this field to simply point to a new instance of `Submittable` but I don't know how to do that.

I know, that I could simply edit the migration file created like so:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        # some dependencies
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
             model_name='Paper',
             name='submittable_ptr_id',
             # here I set default to a function from the Submittable app that just creates a new submittable
             field=models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, default=app1.utils.create_submittable, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key
    =True, serialize=False, to='app1.Submittable'),
             preserve_default=False
        ),
    ]
```

But I want to know if I can specify anything somewhere in `app1` that makes this happen automatically? I don't want users of the app to have to make this change themselves and instead, whenever someone inherits from `Submittable` and runs `makemigrations` the default value should just be set to this callable that creates a new `Submittable`.

Comment: Do you require multi-table inheritance or could you use an abstract class instead?

Comment: I need multi-table inheritance, since one of the functions of `app1` is to relate other models to `Submittable`. For example, it provides a `DeadlineTask` that has a relation to a `Submittable`. So abstract classes does not work..

Answer (score -1):

```
class Submittable(models.Model):
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: This is not working, since I need to be able to add `ForeignKeys` to `Submittables`.

Comment: You can add a primaryKey to Submittable  like this.
paper = models.ForeignKeys(Paper, on_delete=models.CASSCADE, related_name='papers'

Comment: But that's the wrong way around. For example, I have a class `DeadlineTask` that should have a `ForeignKey` to `Submittable` and not specifically to `Paper`. This allows me to use `Submittable` as a sort-of polymorphic superclass.